# Prove that $L \cap HK$ =$ H (L \cap K).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If G is a group, $H \leq L$, and $K \leq G$,then:

Prove that $L \cap HK$ =$ H (L \cap K).$

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Here, $L$ is a subgroup of $G$, or just another group/set that shares some elements and the operation with $G$?

Comment: Just another group @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let $hl \in H(L \cap K)$. Then, since $h \in H \leq L$, $h \in L, l \in L$, so that  $hl \in L$. Also, since $l \in K$, $hl \in HK$. Hence, $hl \in L \cap HK$.

The other way, if an element $j \in L \cap HK$, then since $j \in HK$, we can write $j =hk$, where $h \in H, k \in K$, Now, since $j \in L$, we have that $hk \in L$, so that $h^{-1}(hk) \in L$, so that $k \in L$.

Hence, $k \in (L \cap K)$, and $h \in H$, so that $j = hk \in H(L\cap K)$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: If $G=HK$, I want to show that$L = H(L\cap K)$ under the same given conditions. Can I do so?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can try the method above. Also, it is known that if $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $HK=KH$. You can also try to see  if this gives more useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Let $hk \in L \cap HK$ where $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ (we will think about every element in this way since anything in $L \cap HK$ is also in $HK$). We need to show that $hk \in H(L \cap K)$. Well we have that $H \leq L$ and $hk \in L$ by assumption. Therefore $k \in L$ (recall if one element in a product is in a group both must be). But by assumption as well $k \in K$, so $hk \in H(K \cap L)$ You should see how $L \cap HK \subseteq H(L \cap K)$

Now to show the opposite direction. Let $hp \in H(L \cap K)$ where $h \in H$ and $p \in L \cap K$. Since $p \in L \cap K$, we have $p \in L$ and $p \in K$. Therefore $hp \in HK$. Now we use that $p \in L$ so since $H\leq L$ we must have $hp \in L$. It follows that $hp \in L \cap HK$, so $H(L \cap K) \subseteq L \cap HK $ and therefore since we have both containments $H(L \cap K) = L \cap HK $

You always want to solve problems like this with set containments. Take it one step at a time. Also it is perfectly legitimate to use elements of the form "$hk$" in your proofs when dealing with subsets like $HK$